# Generate Deposit address like binance etc

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I build a crypto exchange. I want to generate ethereum (or Bitcoin) address for deposit. I tried HD wallet but i don't understand.Is there any other way to do this? Or Best Pratices?

Answer (score -1):

The ETH address is just a public key which is derived from the private key. The simpler way to generate the keys is to use a wallet, e.g., Metamask.

So, in simple steps, you can do the following:

1. Install [Metamask](https://metamask.io/)
2. Click "Create Account"
3. You can then click on the Account and "Copy to clipboard". This is your ETH address (public key). For example `0xB7D5D7a6FcFE31611E4673AA3E61f21dC56723fC`.